# "what it is you lack" versus "what you lack"

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses

I was watching an anime and came across to a sentence that I don't fully understand:

> 1. "You must gain ***what it is you lack.***"

In this sentence, what's "what it is you lack" supposed to mean?

And how is it different from:

> 2. "You must gain ***what you lack.***"

Comment: [*You must know **what** you want*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+must+know+what+you+want%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is the shorter and simpler version. There's nothing "wrong" with [*You must know **what it is** you want*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+must+know+what+it+is+you+want%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but that version is over 100 times less common, as the links show. Plus there are a handful of instances of *You must know **what it is that** you want*, which is equally "valid".

Comment: @Araucaria I guess you are right. I couldn't think of that :( I'm so new that I didn't really know how many answers or attention I would get. Also I didn't want to forget to accept an answer. Next time I will be more careful about this. Thank you :)

Comment: @Charlie Keep on asking really good questions! :) I'm a  bit busy, but I might try and give you an answer if I get the chance to check my intuitions with a proper vetted grammar source :-) But anyhow, keep the great questions coming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only different in being a bit wordy, which might be done for emphasis. One could just as well say "you must gain that which you lack". All correct, all same meaning, different sound.

It's probably part of a speech pattern for a particular character. Often in movies a character is partly defined by subtle differences in how he/she uses language.